# how to generate an .ipa file for xamarin.forms app in visual studio

Tags: windows, macos, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, ipa

can you please let me know how to generate an .ipa file for xamarin.forms app from visual studio ? can I generate .ipa file from visual studio on windows machine by virtually connecting mac ?

Comment: Official doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/ios-build-mechanics?tabs=vsmac

Answer (score 2):

1. Add certificates and provisional profiles in mac first.
2. Right click on your ios project. Select Properties.
3. Select certificates and provisional profiles in iOS bundle signing tab.
4. Select IPA options and in release mode checked build iTunes package
   archive(ipa), and provide package name.
5. Just clean and build your project on iphone device.
6. You can find .ipa in your app/ios/bin/iphone/release folder.

for further information link is provided above.
Thanks